# When using Interaction Triggers in WPF to raise MouseDoubleClick, how do I determine which Control was clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, user-interaction

I currently have some Interaction Triggers on a WPF ListView which I use to raise a MouseDoubleClick event, bound to some command in my viewmodel under MVVM Design.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditModeCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

However, this causes a problem where if you click on the GridView under the listview's headers, scroll bar, or whitespace, it will still raise a MouseDoubleClick. If I have no SelectedItem, I get a null instance exception. My command looks as follows:

```
private void CreateEditAction()
    {
        ShowEditView = () =>
        {
            var selectedEvent = ListViewModel.SelectedEvent;
            var selectedEventType = selectedEvent.Type;

            if (selectedEventType == Type.A)
            {
                ShowEditAForm(); 
            }

            if (selectedEventType == Type.B)
            {
                ShowEditBForm();
            }
        };
    }
```

I dont want to just do a null check on the *selectedEvent = ListViewModel.SelectedEvent*, because really you should only get the event raised from clicking on a row in the list. Also, if I did this, it would mean you could select an item in the list, then double click on the column header and get into the editor mode.

How can I determine where the double click came from?

Comment: Why not put the interaction trigger as part of row binding data template rather than under whole ListView?

Comment: I think CommandParamter property can help you here

Comment: @Adarsha do you mean the DataTemplate in the GridViewColumn? The only DataTemplate I have here is:

    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="ListItemViewModel">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

Comment: Ok so I used a CommandParameter and modified the DelegateCommand to template an Object, which i could use as a buffer to check if an event was selected before executing the Editor command.

However, I have also just now decided to just add a CanExecute check to the original command... duh silly me :)